# MalformedURLException HTTPRequest OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: android, httprequest, urlconnection, openweathermap

Project gets data from OpenWeatherMap API and displays them..

I think the error is in configuring the URL and/or using the API key. 
Can anyone help me?

**Code for the connection:**

```
public String getWeatherData (String place) throws IOException {

    // setting things up.., create connection between application and the web, everything we get from the web comes as an inputstream
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    // api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London
    // errors may occur when you connect to the internet, build this in the model with try...catch
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(Utils.BASE_URL + place +"&APPID=f77c39703fb6be71e2c5a96e58edc077")).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        //read the response, buffer "bucket" where you are going to put your data
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        //you get a stream of bits and data to your device - everything comes in as an inputstream
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        //BufferedReader is the only thing that can read the stream of data - hold it and start reading
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = null;

        //line is set as the data read by the BufferedReader, Stringbuffer reads the Buffer and goes to the next one
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer.append(line + "\r\n");
        }

        inputStream.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        return stringBuffer.toString();


    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return null;
}
```

}

**Code for the AsyncTask Methods..** 
  public void renderWeatherData (String city){
    // we want to do all of our tasks in the background, use AsyncTask for this

```
    WeatherTask weatherTask = new WeatherTask();
    weatherTask.execute(new String[]{city} + "&APPID="+ "9df579ecfea4ca7fc67b54965f24b0dd" + "&units=metric");
    }

    //last parameter is Weather, this is what we will be populating
    private class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather>{

    //AsyncTask <PARAMETERS, TASK, RESULT>
        @Override
        protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
            //background computation
            //data variable holds all the data that we have got..
            //instantiate the weather client and get the weather data..

            //getWeatherData gets all necessary data from HTTPClient
            //getWeather parses all the data from the JSONParser


                try {
                    String data = ((new WeatherHTTPClient().getWeatherData(params[0])));
                    weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

                    //create a log to test if everything is working

                    Log.v("Data:",weather.currentCondition.getDescription());

                    return weather;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        //here you will populate the data so you can show it to the user
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
            super.onPostExecute(weather);

            try {
                //gets time and decimal formats and applies it to the data underneath
                DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
                String sunriseDate = df.format(new Date(Weather.place.getSunrise()));
                String sunsetDate = df.format(new Date(Weather.place.getSunset()));
                String updateDate = df.format(new Date(Weather.place.getLastupdate()));

                DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                String tempFormat = decimalFormat.format(weather.currentCondition.getTemperature());

                //follow the paths in the JSON
                cityName.setText(weather.place.getCity() + "," + weather.place.getCountry());
                temp.setText("" + tempFormat + "C");
                humidity.setText("Humidity" + weather.currentCondition.getHumidity() + "%");
                pressure.setText("Pressure" + weather.currentCondition.getPressure() + "hPa");
                wind.setText("Wind" + weather.wind.getSpeed() + "mps");
                sunrise.setText("Sunrise" + sunriseDate);
                sunset.setText("Sunset" + sunsetDate);
                updated.setText("Updated" + updateDate);
                description.setText("Condition" + weather.currentCondition.getCondition() + "(" + weather.currentCondition.getDescription() + ")");

            } catch(Exception e) {
                error = e;
            }
            }
    }


    //create an alert dialog to put in the city you want to parse the data for - A subclass of Dialog that can display one, two or three buttons.

    private void showInputDialog () {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Change City");
        final EditText cityInput = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        cityInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        cityInput.setHint("hint");
        builder.setView(cityInput);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                CityPreference cityPreference = new CityPreference(MainActivity.this);
                cityPreference.setCity(cityInput.getText().toString());

                String newCity = cityPreference.getCity();
                renderWeatherData(newCity);

            }
        });
                builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: You do append your appid twice, in your task as well as before calling it, so that seems wrong

Comment: Hello David, the first one is indeed wrong. I have corrected it.  I still get an error message concerning the URL connection.                                      connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(Utils.BASE_URL + place)).openConnection();